# Ternary operator inside an if-statement that results in nothing

Tags: c#, if-statement, ternary-operator

Ok, I'm probably going about this all wrong, but I can't seem to find a good solution, so any pointers would help.  I have the following statement in my code:

```
if (!mapDict.ContainsKey(_thisRoom.Item1))
        {

            MapGraphItem roomMGI = new MapGraphItem();


            var rndOrderRooms = roomList.OrderBy(i => rnd.Next());
            foreach (MapGraphItem room in rndOrderRooms)
            {
                if (!room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.start) && !room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.exit)
                    && ((_thisRoom.Item2 == 'N') ? room._north : (_thisRoom.Item2 == 'S') ? room._south : (_thisRoom.Item2 == 'E') ? room._east : room._west)
                    && ((mapOpenings.Count < 4) : !room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.deadend) ? *ignore this section*))
                {
                    roomMGI = room;
                    earlyRooms.Add(room);
                    goto Exit;
                }
            }

            Exit:
            //MapGraphItem _room = earlyRooms[rnd.Next(0, earlyRooms.Count)];

            GameObject _roomGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(roomMGI.gameObject, _thisRoom.Item1, Quaternion.identity);
            roomMGI._position = GlobalValues.MapTilePos.Early;
            mapDict.Add(_roomGO.transform.position, roomMGI);

            _mapUsed++;

            if (roomMGI._north) _n = true;
            if (roomMGI._south) _s = true;
            if (roomMGI._east) _e = true;
            if (roomMGI._west) _w = true;

            Debug.Log ("Early room added at: " + _thisRoom.Item1.ToString() + " N? " + (_n ? "yes" : "no") + " S? " + (_s ? "yes" : "no") + 
                " E? " + (_e ? "yes" : "no") + " W? " + (_w ? "yes" : "no"));

            GetRoomOpenings(_roomGO.transform.position, _n, _s, _e, _w);

            _tiles--;
        }
```

Basically, the `*ignore this section*` area means I want nothing to happen.

In other words, assuming the first two lines of the `if` are correct, if the `.Count` is less than four, there's an additional condition.  If `.Count` is four or more, that condition is not needed.

I can't set it to the opposite, just `room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.deadend)` because I don't want it to be forced to be a dead end.  I just want to make sure that it's NOT a dead end if there are fewer than four `mapOpening` left.

Comment: Do you get a prize for using the most ternary operators in a single statement? Because I can't think of any other compelling reason why you wouldn't break some of this up into nested ifs.

Comment: The question - what is the output of this program has a definitive answer - the output is that the developer who wrote it is fired.

Comment: Because the readability of if{if{if{if...}...}...}...} isn't good?  I can easily comment each section of a single if-statement.  And because the resulting body is one set of things or nothing at all.

Comment: LOL so you're saying you actually did this... to IMPROVE readability?

Comment: /sigh - great comments everyone.  Thanks for all the insight.

Comment: Ok, smarty pants, give me a nested if statement with all of those clauses and explain how it makes it more readable.

Comment: you should definitely refine whatever that you wanted to achieve there.  
anyway if you just need ignore the other case you can just replace *ignore this section* with "true".
or use a simple "if" statement

Comment: @JesseWilliams I tend to use the pattern `if (condition) { return; } if (another condition) { return; } do something;` - this avoids the need for nested if statements and makes the code extremely legible.

Comment: That `goto` looks a bit concerning. However, I think it is better to rewrite the code inside the `if ()` with a method that explains what condition it is trying to verify, for instance: `if (IsDeadEnd( ... )) { ... }` would be much more readable and understandable.

Comment: @nhouser9 - I would normally agree, except I basically want a single thing to occur if a whole slew of conditions are met, or for nothing to occur at all.  There are only two outcomes. a and b and c and d and not e and not f means (do something), anything else means (do nothing).  There aren't a bunch of different things to return.

Comment: I HATE goto statements.  Abhor them.  I'm hoping it's a placeholder until I can find a way to break out of both the if-statement and the foreach that this whole thing lives inside of.

Comment: @JesseWilliams see my answer.

Comment: This also highlights the `goto` - otherwise cycles are wasted while the foreach loop continues even after a match is found.

Comment: But in your code above you can use `break` to exit the `foreach` anyway and it does the same thing as `goto Exit`

Comment: `break` would exit the if statement, and then foreach would still run it's next loop.  I could set a boolean in there and use a `while`, I guess.  I know that `goto` are frowned upon, but they still do exist for a reason.

Comment: Yes it will exit the `if`. The `break` is targeted for the first loop statement where it finds itself in and will break out of the `foreach`, `for` or `while` loop. An `if` will end when the runtime either reaches the end of the `if scope` or it reaches a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement. You have no reason these days to use a `goto` statement, in my opinion.

Comment: Sonofa...  I swear I tried this and it wasn't working the way I expected.  My bad.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite

```cs
((mapOpenings.Count < 4)) ? !room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.deadend) : *ignore this section*)
```

as

```cs
((mapOpenings.Count < 4) || !room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.deadend))
```

Comment: Gah, I knew I was missing something simple.  Thank you, @Dandré!

Comment: Ah, that didn't work...  but it does work as an `||` like `&& ((mapOpening.Count > 4) || !room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlbalValues.MapTileType.deadend))`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The below code both answers the question and refactors your code, which is in desperate need of improvement in the legibility department (as noted by many people in the comments).

```
if (room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.start) {
 return;
}

if (room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.exit) {
 return;
}

bool dirFlag = false;
if (_thisRoom.Item2 == 'N') {
 dirFlag = room._north;
}else if (_thisRoom.Item2 == 'S') {
 dirFlag = room._south;
}else if (_thisRoom.Item2 == 'E') {
 dirFlag = room._east;
}else {
 dirFlag = room._west;
}

if (!dirFlag) {
 return;
}

if (mapOpenings.Count < 4 && room._flags.IsFlagSet(GlobalValues.MapTileType.deadend)) {
 return;
}

roomMGI = room;
earlyRooms.Add(room);
goto Exit;
```

Comment: I added more of the code to show why this isn't an option.  I can't just `return` out of it.  It must always get to the inside of the if-statement, and one of the items in rndOrderRooms will always match all required criteria.  But the criteria changes each time, and the order of the rndOrderRooms is, well, randomized so that multiple possible matches aren't always chosen in the same priority.

Comment: @JesseWilliams You can just make my code block a method, call the method, and then its fine to return out of it - that does the EXACT SAME thing as not going in to the if block.

Comment: @JesseWilliams If needed you can make the method return a boolean indicating whether you should jump to the GOTO (which you also shouldn't be using, but that's a different issue)

Comment: Yes, I scrapped the goto.  All of this is proof of concept stuff anyway.  There will be significant refactoring once I make it work :)